# how to update a row having multiple columns and but we want to update few only how can i do it?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to updating the profiles but here I am using that how can I update few columns in a row? please give me suggestions that how can I?. Thanks for advance.

Comment: What part of [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) or [the SQL documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) did you not understand?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to put the required value to the columns and set null or ""-(blank) to the columns which you want empty...

Comment: The question is about *not* changing those other columns.